# ADF Pipeline fails after publishing

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have created an ADF Pipeline that works in Debug mode but fails when published and run.

The job loads a number of tables into Azure SQL from a Dataverse in Data Lake Gen 2.
[image: Pipeline Job]

[image: For Each Entity]

When the published pipeline is triggered, all the "Reload_a_Table" pipelines fail.

[image: Pipeline failures]

[image: Error Message]

What is going on?  How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be multiple reasons for given error.

This error occurred because there is an issue with table name. Please check below 2 points:

1. Do not enter square brackets around table name e.g.  [dbo].[MyTable].
2. Remove whitespaces from table name.

Refer this [article](https://crmchap.co.uk/resolving-unable-to-parse-language-expression-error-in-azure-data-factory-v2/)

Comment: Could not find anything amiss with the JSON.  Eventually rebuilt from scratch to get it working